# Compiling a PHP extension as non-thread-safe

Tags: php, windows, compilation

I am trying to compile the imagemagick (imagick) extension to use in a non-thread-safe environment on windows.

I am using PHP 5.3.10 and have set up Visual C++ express as my compiling environment.
The problem is that I am using a non-thread-safe version of PHP as a FCGI module in Apache 2.2.

Thus, my PHP is supplied with a `php5.lib` and not a `php5ts.lib`. I believe this is the reason why I am getting these errors:

```
imagick.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__tsrm_mutex_alloc referenced in function _zm_startup_imagick
```

I have only ever built and compiled things on linux, so am not too sure how to do this on a windows environment.

How can I compile the extension so that it is non-thread-safe?

---

I downloaded the threadsafe binary of PHP 5.3.10 to get a copy of php5ts.lib. I was then able to compile the extension.

I am guessing that setting the `ZTS` preprocessor directive to either `1` or `0` would cause the extension to compile as either threadsafe or non-thread-safe. (Not too sure about this, so if someone could let me know if this is correct or not, it would be much appreciated. :) )

I then set up a virtual machine running Windows 7 and installed the latest version of WAMP. Reason being that it used a threadsafe version of PHP.

I placed the dll in the ext folder in the PHP installation and enabled it in `php.ini`. However, even after trying both the ts and nts version in WAMP, I would get:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/ext/imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

But the thing is that `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/ext/imagick.dll'` does exist, and yes I have checked this a lot of times.

I then downgraded ImageMagick to 6.6.2-10-Q16, but still see the same problem.

The same issue occurs on my dev machine running a nts version of PHP 5.3.10 on Apache 2.2 (all installed manually).

---

Looks like I could be wrong regarding the `ZTS` preprocessor. If I set `ZTS=0` and compile, using dependency walker on the compiled dll still shows that it requires `php5ts.dll` which is only present on threadsafe versions of PHP.

---

I did more tinkering with dependency walker and found that I had to statistically link to msvc100d.dll. I then removed `ZTS` in the preprocessor definition and was able to compile using `php5.lib` instead of `php5ts.dll`. I think this should get me a non-ts dll.

However, when loading the extension, I am still getting:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'imagick.dll' in Unknown on line 0
```

And errors from dependency walker:

```
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
```

---

Installed visual c++ express 2008 and compiled using platform toolkit v90, but still facing the same issues.

Any tips appreciated :)

---

## **Solution Found! See my answer.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it! I hope this can help those compiling php extensions on windows in the future. What I have done is based on: https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

Note: I read an answer on this site that said compiling PHP extensions by itself on windows is unsupported. Based on my experiments yesterday, it seems to be a lot of work as well, so I am using the PHP build process.

The best way is to use the PHP build process.

1. Install Visual C++ Express 2008 (any version will do, but express is free) and Windows SDK 6.1 (note that we want the 6.1 version not anything older or newer).
2. Install the [SVN client tools](https://sliksvn.com/download/) if you haven't done so and restart for your `PATH` variable to take effect.
3. Get the [PHP SDK binary tools](https://windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/) and extract it to `C:\php-sdk`.
4. Start the `CMD Shell` under `Microsoft Windows SDK v6.1` in your start menu and run `cd C:\php-sdk`.
5. Run `setenv /x86 /xp /release` this creates a 32-bit release. You can use `/x64` to build a 64-bit release (I have not tried this).
6. run `bin\phpsdk_setvars.bat`
7. run `bin\phpsdk_buildtree.bat php53dev`
8. Download the [PHP source code](https://www.php.net/downloads.php) and extract it to `C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86`  so that you end up with `C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86\php5.3-xyz`
9. Download the latest [deps](https://windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/) and extract everything to `C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86`. You may be prompted to overwrite any existing folders, so press yes.
10. run `cd C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86`
11. Check out the latest version of your extension from the svn repository: `svn co http://svn.php.net/repository/pecl/imagick/trunk pecl/imagick` I am checking out imagick here.
12. Install any dependencies. In my case, I need to install ImageMagick, so I downloaded the latest recommended [windows binary](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows). You will need to restart after installation to update your `PATH` variable, but you can do this after you have compiled. Make sure you install the C/C++ headers and includes as well.
13. Copy the contents of the `includes` directory from the ImageMagick install directory to `C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86\deps\include`.
14. Copy the contents of the `lib` directory from the ImageMagick install directory to `C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86\deps\lib`
15. Now, let's build: run `cd C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86\php5.3-xyz` then `buildconf` then `configure --help`. Look at the help properly. It will show you all config flags and any avaliable extensions to enabled. In my case, since I added imagick, I had an option called `--with-imagick`
16. Run config: `configure --enable-cli --with-imagick=shared --disable-zts` If you want to build a non-thread-safe binary use `--disable-zts`, otherwise remove that configuration flag. I am not sure why, but sometimes extensions use the `--with-myextension` flag and sometimes `--enable-myextension`, so check `configure --help` for the flag to use. If you add `=shared` after the extension flag, it will be compiled as a separate DLL, which si what we want.
17. Compile: run `nmake` then `nmake snap`.
18. Done :) Check `C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86\php-5.3.10\Release` (non-thread-safe) or `C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86\php-5.3.10\Release_TS` (thread-safe). Your compiled binaries should be in there. The compiled extensions (pecl), should be in a ZIP file similiar to `pecl-5.3.10-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.zip`. Open this file and extract the extensio DLL to your `ext` folder in your PHP installation.
19. Enable the PHP extension and restart your webserver. Run `phpinfo()` and check that the extension is enabled.
20. If the extension does not work properly, make sure you reboot to update your `PATH` variable. In my case, I need to have the imagemagick install directory in my `PATH` variable.
21. ???
22. Profit!

Comment: I want to thank you for taking time writing this beautiful piece of instructions. Really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to compile? Why not download? It's usually much simpler/quicker on Windows.

VC6: http://www.sk89q.com/2010/03/vc6-windows-binaries-for-imagick-2-3-0/

VC9: http://valokuva.org/builds/

Comment: I tried the builds from Valokuva.org, but they didn't work on my manually installed server or WAMP. The binaries from sk89q.com also did not work. That's why I want to compile 3.1.0b1 against the latest version of imagemagick.

Comment: I meant 3.1.0rc1 not 3.1.0b1.