# Imagick not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagemagick, thumbnails

I am working on creating thumbnail image from the first page of pdf file. I almost tired every solution available on the web to make ImageMagick running but I still get the following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in C:\wamp\www\mediabox\application\controllers\cron.php on line 153
```

what I have done so far.

1. Installed GPL Ghostscript
2. Installed ImageMagick-6.7.6-Q16
3. Downloaded and copied the php_imagick.dll file in ext folder of my php installation.
4. Added extension=php_imagick.dll line to my php.ini file.
5. Restarted the apache server and windows many times :)
6. I am using codeigniter framework.
7. Php 5.3.10, apache 2.2.21, mysql 5.5.20, wamp 2.2 and win 7

On my localhost page in the loaded extensions category 'Imagemagick is not listed'

The code I have written is as

```
$image = explode('.', $filename_new);
$image_name = 'files/import/' . $ftp_upload["path"] ."/". $image[0] .".jpg";
//exec("convert -colorspace RGB -geometry 300x400! -density 200 " .$pdf_file."[0] ". $image_name);  
$img = $image[0].".jpg" ;
$im = new Imagick($img);
$im->pingImage($img);
$im->readImage($img);
$im->thumbnailImage(100, null);
$im->writeImage( 'files/import/' . $ftp_upload["path"] ."/".$img);
$im->destroy();
```

The exec command create images but it is very slow I want to create thumbnail images using Imagick class and I hope it will be faster as compared to exec and convert thingy.

Any ideas what should I do to make the Imagick class available for my php ?

Thanks

Comment: check your `phpinfo()` to see if you have an extension called `imagick` first. This should confirm whether the `imagick` extension was installed correctly.

Comment: no it does not have imagick extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure where you got your binaries from, but it seemed like something I experienced about a month ago. Some of the binaries I tried would show up in `phpinfo()`, but refused to work, whereas others wouldn't even show in `phpinfo()`.

I then just went ahead and compiled my own binaries as per my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084493/compiling-a-php-extension-as-non-thread-safe).

I just went and compiled those binaries for you. They are for x86, compiled with VC9 and there are threadsafe and non-threadsafe versions. The version is 3.1.0RC1 (latest).

You can download them here: http://min.us/mtg0Z66BI

Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: I'll see if I can build an x64 version :)

Comment: So should I try your solution for 64x or not ? :)

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhh :( and do you think using Imagick class will b more efficient then using the exec command with convert or not ?

Comment: I don't think there should be much difference.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find any x64 dependencies here: http://windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/, so couldn't compile  x64 version :(

Comment: A possible solution: use the 32bit version of WAMP and use my 32-bit binaries.

Comment: @F21, Thanks for compiling this PHP extension. Unfortunately, the link seems unbroken : download doesn't work anymore. Could you update it?

Comment: @sdespont: Here is the reuploaded extension: http://www.mediafire.com/?lo819uacsza91rx Note that this is compiled for PHP 5.4 32bit non-thread-safe vc9.

Comment: @F21, thanks about your quick answer => +1! I am looking for PHP 5.3 32 bits VC9 thread safe version. Exactly like your main answer link. Do you have this PHP extension? BTW I have recently opened a topic about where to find this extension (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395652/where-to-download-imagick-php-extension-vc6-and-vc9), I will add your link.

Answer (score 1):

On my server the pecl-imagick extension only works with mod_mpm_prefork - it does not work with mod_mpm_worker.so or mod_mpm_event.so

That may be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only creating jpg add the jpg hint to the exec( ) command which will be faster than Imagick.

Use -define jpeg:size=200x200 before reading the image in - 200x200 is the output image size.

I suspect Imagick is not installed correctly

Comment: You mean including the -define jpeg option will fast the exec command ?

Comment: Not sure with a pdf but it is only supposed to read enough data into memory to create the jpg and so it is faster. Some speed tests I carried out a year or so ago: http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/speed/Speed_tests_1.pdf