# Where to download iMagick PHP extension VC6 and VC9

Tags: php, imagick, php-extension

I would like to use [iMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) with my PHP web page, but I can't find where to download an official PHP extension for Windows compiled with code http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick

I found some links on the web like :

1. http://valokuva.org/outside-blog-content/imagick-windows-builds/php53/imagick-2.3.0-dev/
2. http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-extensions/imagick.html

But some PHP extensions are very old and makes Apache crash, others are working.

And how can I trust the DLL code inside?

Is there a trusted web site where I could donwload iMagick PHP extension compiled with VC6 and VC9?

Comment: just grab from downloads: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but there is no php extension to download on this page

Comment: look at this guide: http://www.elxsy.com/2009/07/installing-imagemagick-on-windows-and-using-with-php-imagick/

Comment: Thanks for your link, but once again, the DLL is an old one (2009) and the web site seems to be a blog http://valokuva.org. Still no offical release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try to have a look here](http://www.mediafire.com/php-win64-extensions) usually these extensions work quite well.

For production server is better to compile it from source code using PECL, Visual Studio or Windows SDK

[Imagemagick source codes on Pecl](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick)

[How to build php extension on Windows](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/244215-introduction-to-creating-a-php-extension-for-windows/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it is just a repository managed by an unknown user. Furthermore, there is 0 downloads for almost all files. It doesn't seem to be official rand profesional release

Comment: Well on live server I wouldn't use Windows (for php), even that I use it as development environment, I don't think it's professional either ;-)

Comment: I agree but I can't choice my customer IT infrastructure :o/

Comment: Ok, I understand, then compile it.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, it is the best idea. Update your answer with your comment, perhaps share a "how to " link and I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also spent hours trying to install imagick on windows 7. Only this solution worked https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html
It tells exact versions that will work with my system. Please note that usually windows are 64 bits but php on xampp has x84